# How to get the report data into list in apex class

Tags: apex, api, reporting, analytics

Can any one help me how to get report data into apex class as a list.

Thanks,

Murali

Comment: Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). The more details you provide, particularly code you've written, the more likely it is that someone will respond to your question with an answer you'll find helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SFDC provides programmatic access to reports via Analytics API & inbuilt classes in Reports namespace.

For more info check this link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_Reports.htm

Here is sample code for your reference:

```
// Get the report ID
List <Report> reportList = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM Report where 
    DeveloperName = 'Closed_Sales_This_Quarter'];
String reportId = (String)reportList.get(0).get('Id');

// Run a report synchronously
Reports.reportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true);

// Get the first down-grouping in the report
Reports.Dimension dim = results.getGroupingsDown();
Reports.GroupingValue groupingVal = dim.getGroupings()[0];
System.debug('Key: ' + groupingVal.getKey());
System.debug('Label: ' + groupingVal.getLabel());
System.debug('Value: ' + groupingVal.getValue());

// Construct a fact map key, using the grouping key value
String factMapKey = groupingVal.getKey() + '!T';

// Get the fact map from the report results
Reports.ReportFactWithDetails factDetails =
    (Reports.ReportFactWithDetails)results.getFactMap().get(factMapKey);

// Get the first summary amount from the fact map
Reports.SummaryValue sumVal = factDetails.getAggregates()[0];
System.debug('Summary Value: ' + sumVal.getLabel());

// Get the field value from the first data cell of the first row of the report
Reports.ReportDetailRow detailRow = factDetails.getRows()[0];
System.debug(detailRow.getDataCells()[0].getLabel());
```

Comment: Hi , could you please help me with my similar kind of question??  Link: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167555/how-to-get-my-data-into-javascript-chart-by-parsing-report-data