# LWC - build a list of reports as clickable links

Tags: lightning-web-components, reporting

I am currently building an LWC that displays a list of reports in my org, describes what their purpose is, and then provides a link to each one of them next to their name that takes the user to the actual report. The issue I'm running into is that if I hard code the links to the report in the LWC, the component will break when I deploy the code to upper testing environments because report Id's are not shared among different sandboxes -- so I'm currently trying to set a dynamic URL for each report in the LWC display component so that it will get the id of the report no matter which sandbox it's in. I'm thinking I need to query for the report in the JS file of the LWC and then store it in a variable that I can then use in the html file of the LWC. Am I on the right track or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Yes, you want to [call the API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_resource_reference.htm) in your controller to generate a list of reports. Better way to approach this would be to not do what you're doing. A list of reports is already available out of the box via Reports tab (see list views to filter) or [new Analytics "home" (app)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_rd_reports_unified_home_beta.htm&type=5&release=238)

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide me with an example of generating a list of reports in the controller by utilizing the API?

Comment: See the first few lines of this example; https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89414/how-to-get-the-report-data-into-list-in-apex-class If the example doesn't make sense, please go through Apex beginner tutorials on Trailhead. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database

Answer (score 2):

You can get the all Report details using SOQL.

```
SELECT Id, Description, Name, DeveloperName FROM Report
```

Reender the list of reports, using [`for:each`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_lists) directive to iterate over an array. Add the directive to a nested  tag that encloses the HTML elements you want to repeat.

Inside the list, add buttons with `data-id={report.Id}` so that you can get the report Id in the event handler.

```
<lightning-button data-id={report.Id} variant="neutral" label="Go To Report" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
```

Finally use [NavigationMixin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) to navigate to the report on button click.

```
handleClick(event) {
    let targetId = event.target.dataset.id;
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: targetId,
            objectApiName: 'Report',
            actionName: 'view'
        }
    });        
}
```